# Calculate time difference in minutes in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table in SQL server 2008 with data.
Table contains data with amount of time organization has worked on request

```
CREATE TABLE support 
(    ID varchar(50), 
     IN_ORGANIZATION varchar(MAX),    
     FROM_ORGANIZATION varchar(MAX),
     TIMEDIF datetime                );

INSERT INTO support
(ID, IN_ORGANIZATION,FROM_ORGANIZATION,TIMEDIF )


VALUES
('22907','ORGANIZATION_NAME_1','RODLAY LLP','2017-04-15 14:58:00.000'),

('22907','MARY LOAN','ORGANIZATION_NAME_1','2017-04-15 15:00:00.000'),


('23289','VENIXTON Ltd','ORGANIZATION_NAME_1','2017-04-21 11:00:00.000'),

('23289','ORGANIZATION_NAME_1','Ocean Loan','2017-04-21 12:00:00.000'),

('23289','Ocean Loan','ORGANIZATION_NAME_1','2017-04-21 13:00:00.000')

;
```

I want to find time work organizations with the request: ORGANIZATION_NAME_1.
    Help me write CURSOR to calculate the time.

```
Result:
ID, TIMEDIF(minutes)
22907, 2
23289, 120
```

Comment: I don't understand how you arrived at the expected output.  I think it should be 120 minutes, not 180, but in any case please clarify.  Also, it's helpful if you show us data in the form of a _table_, formatted as code by adding 4 spaces to the start of each line.

Comment: What is the logic for TIMEDIF? How are you determining what the value should be? And you do NOT want a cursor for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Datediff** function will do the trick

```
select id,datediff(minute,min(timedif),max(timedif) ) AS time from support 
where in_organization = 'ORGANIZATION_NAME_1' or from_organization = 'ORGANIZATION_NAME_1'  
group by id ;
```

**My Output:**

```
    |id     |time
1   |22907  |2
2   |23289  |120
```

Let tme know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this query will help you:

```
select 
   id, 
   DATEDIFF(m,MIN(TIMEDIF),MAX(TIMEDIF)) as [TIMEDIF(minutes)] 
from support
    where IN_ORGANIZATION ='ORGANIZATION_NAME_1' 
       or FROM_ORGANIZATION ='ORGANIZATION_NAME_1'
group by id
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just arbitrarily trying to get the TimeDifferences between rows you could try something like this:

```
; WITH x AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS rwn
From dbo.support
)
SELECT 
  x.ID
, y.ID AS NextID
, x.IN_ORGANIZATION
, y.IN_ORGANIZATION NextInOrg
, x.FROM_ORGANIZATION
, y.FROM_ORGANIZATION NextFromOrg
, x.TIMEDIF
, y.TIMEDIF AS NextTimeDiff
, x.rwn
, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, x.TIMEDIF, y.TIMEDIF) AS DifferenceFromOneToTheNext
FROM x 
    INNER JOIN x y ON x.rwn = y.rwn - 1
```

If you put in an identity that self seeds you can already get a pointer for reference.  This is really arbitrary though.